Convertion of XML file to CSV in NIFI, Doesn't work

I am new to NiFi, Working on conversion of xml content to csv.

While doing conversion of xml file to csv struck with the output in a flowfile.
Output of the flowfile in convertrecord 
xmlHeader,Data,tag10
"MapRecord[{attr1=9.093, attr2=ralg, tag1=MapRecord[{attr3=ral2}],
tag2=MapRecord[{attr4=2024-01-02}]}]",MapRecord[{tag3=[Ljava.lang.Object;@134b8291}],
MapRecord[{tag10=MapRecord[{attr10=attr10_value}]}]

Processors used in making flow are
GetFile --> UpdateAttribute --> ConvertRecord --> updateAttribute --> PutFile.


Configured controlservices like xmlReader and CSVRecordSetWriter with infer schema and inherit record Shcema respectively.
Expecting output with comma separated values like below.
namespace, attr1, attr2,att3,attr4,attr5,attr6,attr7,attr8,tag6_value,attr9,tag8_value
namespace, attr1, attr2,att3,attr4,attr5,attr6,attr7,attr8,tag6_value,attr9,tag8_value


Sample Input xml is.

<root namespace="namespace_value">
<xmlHeader attr1="9.093" attr2="ralg">
<tag1 attr3="ral2"/>
<tag2 attr4="2024-01-02"/>
</xmlHeader>
<Data>
<oneelement/>
<tag3 att5="attr5_value">
<tag4 attr6="attr6_value" attr7="attr7_value"/>
<tag5 attr8="attr8_value"/>
<tag6>tag6_value</tag6>
<tag7 attr9="attr9_value">
<tag8>tag8_value</tag8>
</tag7>
</tag3>
</Data>
<Data>
<oneelement/>
<tag3 att5="attr5_value">
<tag4 attr6="attr6_value" attr7="attr7_value"/>
<tag5 attr8="attr8_value"/>
<tag6>tag6_value</tag6>
<tag7 attr9="attr9_value">
<tag8>tag8_value</tag8>
</tag7>
</tag3>
</Data>
<tag9>
<tag10 attr10="attr10_value"/>
</tag9>
</root>


Conversion of above mentioned XML to CSV in NiFi gives output, which is above shared. Anything more need to be configured while doing conversion.
Alternatively also tried with Avro schema registry with proper avro format, but still the output is not csv format.

Any quick help is much appreciated.

What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What output do you get, and what were you expecting instead? What command or code do you use? Any errors? Is that image the actual output? Would be better to replace this with a text version. See also [ask].

Image output is included.  Updated with steps which have been tried.
